# Bootstrap DateTimePicker format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, format, cultureinfo, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application and am using the [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) in a view.

My application is being used internationally and I would like to format the datetimepicker to have the correct format for each user. I have the culture and the timezone for each user, how is the best way to format the datetimepicker to the correct user's format? Should I use the format property, locales, or a different technique?

I am currently getting the `DateTimeFormat` object from a `Culture` object. This has the following values:

```
ShortDatePattern

ShortTimePattern
```

I am then trying to set the datetimepicker as follows:

```
$(function () {
    $('#displayMapLocationStartDate').datetimepicker(
    {
        format: '**combination of culture object**',
    });
});
```

Is this the best way to write the code for the datetimepicker to be in the correct format for each different user's culture? If not, how should this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You reference the .NET `Culture` object, but then show a hard-coded value in your JavaScript?

Comment: Can you have a look at my edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bootstrap datetimepicker internally uses Moment.js for formatting, and Moment's formatting codes differ to .NET's. For example, .NET uses `dd` for day of month with leading digit (01...31), but Moment uses `DD` for the same thing. So the code you posted above will not work as intended.

You will need to write a translation method that takes in a .NET date/time format string and spits out a Moment-compatible version, which you can then use when setting the `datetimepicker.format` property.

Comment: format of `format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',` brings me the date format what I expect `30/11/2021`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [the Momentjs docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), you'll see that they provide locale aware format tokens `L` (date) and `LT` (time).

Both of these tokens are accepted strings to the pickers `format` setting.

As long as you include the `moment-with-locales.js` or `moment.js` with the proper locale file, you can use either token to do what you want.

```
$('#displayMapLocationStartDate').datetimepicker(
{
    format: 'L',
});
```

Comment: thank you random down voter for not giving an explanation.

Comment: Wasn't me on the downvote, but I'm not getting the above to work with changing locales. Tried setting data-date-format='L' in the HTML and also tried your js call. Both end up resulting in my standard US M/D/Y formatting. If I use 'DD/MM/YYYY', then all is well. I would have guessed L and LT would work, but I'm just not seeing it, so will end up writing the translation like the answer above. Thanks for a great library!